# sendmail: User unknown

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am trying to run mail (or sendmail) from exadata lnux server and getting 'dead.letter' error. `/var/log/maillog` file shows `stat=User unknown`

I even tried to update `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file and changed 'SMART_HOST' entry, still does not work.

```
/home/oracle/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/oracle/dead.letter 

pri=30068, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

Comment: it would seem to me that the SMTP server needs to be defined somewhere in the configuration of Linux or on the commandline when the mail command is run.

Comment: User unknown? That's me! Put me on BCC! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you rebuild `sendmail.cf` after editing `sendmail.mc` and restart sendmail? Also handy to know might be what domains sendmail considers itself local for, e.g. via `echo '$={w}' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt`

Otherwise, for a simple client-that-sends-mail-elsewhere configuration, altering `submit.mc` (and rebuilding `submit.cf`) may suffice to send mail off to some other host (provided there is a client mqueue queue runner or daemon the resend messages should that host be down) via an appropriate `msp` line:

```
FEATURE(`msp', `datsmarthost.example.com')dnl
```

In this case the main sendmail daemon need not be run (possibly just the client mail queue runner, or a cron job could handle that).

Comment: yes, i did rebuild sendemail.cf. I followed these steps:
1.1. changes to /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
 
Uncomment the definition SMART_HOST and add the correspondign FEATURE to it:
define(`SMART_HOST', `your-smtp-server')
FEATURE(authinfo)dnl

Comment: 1.2. Create the new sendmail.cf
 
Stop sendmail by issuing the command /sbin/service sendmail stop and log on as root to issue this command:
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
 
 
1.3. Define the account information for connecting to the smtp-server
 
Edit/create /etc/mail/authinfo and add the following line:
AuthInfo:<your-smtp-server> "U:<your-smtp-user>" "P:<your-smtp-password>" "M:DIGEST-MD5"
 
Note:The M: may vary depending on the capabilities of the smtp-server (e.g. CRAM-MD5, PLAIN).
 
Create authinfo.db:
makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo < /etc/mail/authinfo

Comment: and finally restart sendmail:
/sbin/service sendmail restart

Comment: any more information?

Comment: Again, what domains does your sendmail consider itself local for?